# Paginate_links in custom post type template

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives

I'm trying to display the paginate_links function within a custom post type. But it does not show up on the site. Here is the loop:

```
<div class="container">
    <?php
        $objekte_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'objekte',
            'posts_per_page' => '1'
         )
     ?>
        <?php $objekte = new WP_Query( $objekte_args ); ?>
        <?php if ( $objekte->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( $objekte->have_posts() ) : $objekte->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-push-1 col-md-4">
                <h2>
                    <?php _e( 'Objekte', 'ryvola' ); ?>
                </h2>
                <div class="projects__project-title">
                    <span class="projects__project-title--headline"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div>
                <?php echo paginate_links( array(
                    'format' => '?paged=%#%'
                )); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        <?php else : ?>
        <p>
            <?php _e( 'default', 'ryvola' ); ?>
        </p>
        <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are missing most of the arguments for the function. Even though the docs say they are optional arguments, you will get no output without setting them.

Comment: Tried it with copying in the default arguments from wordpres codex. Still no output.

Comment: The default for total is 1, meaning a single page. You need to set those things to the actual values in your query, not their defaults.

Comment: following from @Milo's suggestion, please read for example https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links#Example_With_a_Custom_Query

Comment: I managed to get the pagination displayed but the links dont work. For example /objekte/page/2 gives me an 404 error? I refreshed the permalinks in settings but it didn't help.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this and check whether its working for you or not?

```
<div class="container">
    <?php
    // set up or arguments for our custom query
    $paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
    $objekte_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'objekte',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'paged' => $paged
    );
     ?>
        <?php $objekte = new WP_Query( $objekte_args ); ?>
        <?php if ( $objekte->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( $objekte->have_posts() ) : $objekte->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-push-1 col-md-4">
                <h2>
                    <?php _e( 'Objekte', 'ryvola' ); ?>
                </h2>
                <div class="projects__project-title">
                    <span class="projects__project-title--headline"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div>
                <?php echo paginate_links( array(
                    'format' => '?paged=%#%'
                )); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        <?php else : ?>
        <p>
            <?php _e( 'default', 'ryvola' ); ?>
        </p>
        <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not working, will try it now with more arguments to the paginate_links function